# Microcontroller Power Supplies and Power Sequencing

Tags: microcontroller, power

I am using this [MCP5606S Microcontroller](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPC5606S.pdf) in my design. However, I am finding it difficult to understand its power Supplies. Then, I went to the Manufacturer website and downloaded the [MPC5606S Reference Manual](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/MPC5606SRM.pdf) for better understanding of the Power Supplies. Unfortunately, I am not able to get clarity. In the Reference Manual, Chapter 40, Page No. 1227, they are talking about Power Supplies. Can someone explain me in simpler terms about the internal power or regulators that they mention inside the MCU. Like how to power them and which one should I power first. I am trying to design the power sequencing. So, if anyone can provide clarity, I would be really grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you had a close look on chapter 3.7 Power management electrical characteristics in the datasheet (page 65 and following)? They have some external component schematics and power on and off sequencing diagrams there.

Comment: Yes. I was not able to get clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 requirements from what I can see:

1. The generic I/O power (see section 2.5 in the datasheet) should all ramp up together and *can* precede \$V_{DDR}\$ although \$V_{DDR}\$ can ramp up *with* the generic I/O power; the LV supply should follow this.
2. In section 3.4.1 (Recommended operating conditions for 3.3V operation) there is a caution:

> VDDE_C and VDDA must be the same voltage.
>
> VDDMB and VDDMC must be the same voltage.

I take that to mean they *must* be supplied from the same source. This could easily be overlooked as they are stepper motor supplies where a designer might (for thermal purposes) use separate regulators but here that should **not** be done.

Apart from that, there does not appear to be any other sequencing or supply dependencies.

There are some general guidelines in section 3.4.2:

> **Connecting power supply pins: What to do and what not to do**
>
> • Do: — Have all power/ground supplies connected on the board from a
> strong supply source rather than weak voltage divider sources unless
> there is “NO I/O activity” in the section
>
> — Meet the supply
> specifications for max / typical operating conditions to guarantee
> correct operation
>
> — Place the decoupling near the supply/ground pin
> pair for EMI emissions reduction
>
> — Route high-noise supply/ground away
> from sensitive signals (for example, ADC channels must be away from
> SMD supply/motor pads)
>
> — Use star routing for the ballast supply from the VDDR supply to
> avoid ballast startup noise injected to VDDR supply of the device
>
> — Use LC inductive filtering for ADC, OSC, and PLL supplies if these are
> generated from common board regulators
> • Do not:
>
> — Violate injection current limit per I/O or All I/O pins as per specifications
>
> — Connect sensitive supplies/ground on noisy supplies/ground (that is, ADC, PLL, and OSC)
>
> — Use SMD supply for generation of noise free supply as these
> are most noisy lines in the system
>
> — Connect different VDD pins (connected together inside the device) to different potentials.

These are all reasonable guidelines.

Comment: On shut down the IO voltage must ramp down after the main regulator voltage: The VDD IO HV supply must be disabled after the VDDREG HV supply voltage drops below 1.5 V. This is to ensure that the 1.2 V regulator shuts down before the 3.3 V regulator shuts down. (page 73)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Can you just help me understanding the HPREG, LPREG,ULPREG mentioned in Figure 40.1, Page number 1228, of the reference manual. Are they internal regulators present inside the module? What purpose do these 3 regulators serve?

Comment: Can someone help me? Please